# ngbindHtml onchange detect angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

So I am using `ng-bind-html` to display html data stored in the `CurrentContent`

```
<div ng-bind-html="CurrentContent" ></div>
```

I wonder when I use Jquery to update the content inside of the `CurrentContent`, such as I add

```
<h1>Tittle</h1>
```

`CurrentContent` in Angular would update as Jquery updated it, I tried add ngChange into

```
'<div ng-bind-html="CurrentContent" ngChange="Updated()"></div>'
```

But it gives me an error, how can I updated it dynamically?

Comment: How is jQuery used to update CurrentContent ?

Comment: It looks like you are updating the variable outside of the digest cycle... call the update code inside `$scope.$apply(function(){})` and see

Comment: @Mahesh Sapkal  using jquery sortable to insert element into the <ul> tag inside of the  <div ng-bind-html="CurrentContent" ></div>